# Custom Data label for Flex 4 Pie Chart

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, itemrenderer, custom-component, pie-chart

Does anyone know that it is possible if it is possible to create an item renderer for the data labels of a Flex Pie Chart?

i know it is possible to change the formatting of the String using the label function. But i need more control of the way the data label appears.

The background of the label needs to be a a specific color based on the data.

Thank you in advance for any help you may provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private function pieSeries_labelFunc(item:Object, field:String, index:Number, percentValue:Number):String {
    //process string and return it 
}
```

in your mxml add this hope this will help

```
<mx:PieSeries id="pieSeries"
       labelFunction="pieSeries_labelFunc" />
 </mx:series>
```

[Creating custom DataTip renderers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c28.html)

> Refer this link for creating costume tool tip

Comment: thank you for that but this only solves half the problem. I can format the String but it is the actual style of the label that i need to change. 

For Exmaple i need to change the background colour of the label so that if the data is a negative number the background colour is red and if it is a positive number the background of the label is green